# Copy content of img file to another img file

Tags: c, fopen, binaryfiles, argv

I am trying to make a function that opens 2 files- one for reading and the other one for writing and then copies the first file into the other one binary and for some reason its just does not work. I was trying to debug the program few times but i could not recognize the problem.

```
void myCopyBinary(char * * argv) {
FILE * srcFile;
FILE * dstFile;
int yesNo = 0;
char temp = ' ';
int i = 0;
int size = 0;
char * buffer;
int resultFread = 0;
int resultFwrite = 0;

srcFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

if (srcFile != NULL) {
  dstFile = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
  if (dstFile != NULL) {
    printf("Would you like to overwrite it? (Every Number -YES, 0-NO): ");
    scanf("%d", & yesNo);

    if (yesNo == 0) {
      fclose(dstFile);
      exit(0);
      return 1;
    }
  }
  dstFile = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

  if (dstFile != NULL) {
    fseek(srcFile, 0, SEEK_END); // non-portable
    size = ftell(srcFile);
    buffer = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    if (buffer == NULL) {
      printf("Error with the buffer!\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    do {
      resultFread = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), srcFile);
      resultFwrite = fwrite(buffer, 1, resultFread, dstFile);
    } while (resultFread > 0);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not just use `cp file1 file2`?

Comment: What if it's an 800GB file? It might not be a good idea to try and read the whole thing into memory...

Comment: How are you calling this routine?

Comment: This is the mission, did you notice any problems in the code?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: look at that last while loop... I often test constructions such as this one with a buffer set to some ridiculous small size - and there is no need for a buffer being the size of the original file!

Answer (score 3):

One a side note, before reopening the `dstFile` for writing you should close the previous descriptor.

Anyways, you called `fseek(srcFile, 0, SEEK_END);`, however you didn't seek back to the beginning, thus when you attempt to read you hit `EOF`. I guess this is the root of your problem, if not(or rather after fixing this it still doesn't work) then please give more details how it does not work.